# simple PHP CMS with INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php property rental system CMS. Right now I am stuck on adding new property to a database.

My database:

```
properties: propertyId, imageId, town, num of rooms etc..
```

`propertyid` is primary key auto increment, imageId is foreign key

```
images: imageId, image (image path with image name)
```

`imageId` is primary key auto increment:

So in my PHP I have 2 SQL statements when adding new property to database (please correct me if this is not good way of doing this).

First insert into images values ("imagepath/imagename.jpg").

Second query inserts into properties values (town, numOfrooms etc).

So I have inserted an image into a database and then I want to insert property to database, I have error checking there after I click on add property,

I got message that "image was saved successfully" to a database but then i got error saying:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails : CONSTRAINT `properties_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`imageId`) REFERENCES `images` (`imageId`))

Is this right way of doing this where I first insert image and then I insert property?

Comment: you need do 2 things ... insert image to database which return self id. Second you insert properties and set image id what you have now. Is good way doing this in transaction (if your database engine have this)

Comment: thanks i havent learn transaction yet, just found similar problem here on stackoverflow and solution was using php function mysql_insert_id() is this what you meant?

Comment: yes you are right .. you do insert after call mysql_insert_id() .. it returns new id inserted image next you set this id into second insert and it should be ok ... transaction are good if something failed during insertion process you have always consistent data

Comment: so i just tried that and i get php error :
 Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\phpProject\admin\properties-add.php on line 40

and mysqli_error:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`propertyrentalsystem`.`properties`, CONSTRAINT `properties_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`imageId`) REFERENCES `images` (`imageId`))

Comment: here is my full sql statements:

Comment: $propAddImageQuery = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO 
images(image) 
VALUES
('$imagepath')");

$id = mysql_insert_id();


$propAddQuery = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO properties(
street,
town,
imageId,
content) 
VALUES (
 '$street', 
'$town', 
'$id',
'$content')");

Comment: so i got it working
i had to use $imageId = mysqli_insert_id($connection); 
where connection is my actual database connection
thanks

Comment: you call all other funcions on current connection because they working with database and they need to know which have selected

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to add the property to the same row you just added the image in you need to use UPDATE not INSERT
Over simplified example

```
UPDATE propertyName WHERE image = imageIJustInserted
```

Once you've inserted/created a row you can really only update it. You can't insert into it again.

Comment: thanks i see where you going with update statement, not sure if this will help me in my case

in my properties table  i have field imageId(int) that i have to insert and i dont know how to get image id of image just inserted 

if iam right

Comment: Oh okay i didn't read it correctly, sorry. Dare machine is correct in the comments

Answer (score 0):

so i got it working
i had to use $imageId = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
where connection is my actual database connection
i got imageId of an image just inserted and then i could use it inside second insert statement
thanks